# Sigmajs v2 unable to load module

Tags: requirejs, sigma.js

I need advise on how can I load SigmaJS v2 on a html document?

Here are the steps I did, but it is not working

Step 1) I created a new folder and open a cmd window, then execute the below command

> npm install graphology sigma

Step 2) I download the require.js in cdn and put inside the node_modules/sigma/require.js
Step 3) I created a new file called index.html in the node_modules/sigma/index.html.
Below is my code for index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>var exports = {};</script>
    <script>var module = {};</script>

    <script src="require.js"></script>
    
    <style>
        html { height:100%; color: #fff!important;}
        body {height: 100%; margin:0; color: #fff!important;}
        #sigma-container { width:100%; height:100%;  color: #fff!important;}
        #sigma-mouse{
           background: transparent;
        }
    </style>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onload(){
            require([
                "sigma.js",
                "../events/events.js"
            ], function(){
                var s = new sigma(
                  {
                    renderer: {
                      container: document.getElementById('sigma-container'),
                      type: 'canvas'
                    },
                    settings: {
                     labelColor: 'node',
                     minEdgeSize: 0.1,
                     maxEdgeSize: 2,
                     minNodeSize: 5,
                     maxNodeSize: 5,
                    }
                  }
                );

                var graph = {
                  nodes: [
                    { id: "n0", label: "node 1", x: 0, y: 0, size: 3, color: '#00BCD4' },
                    { id: "n1", label: "node 2", x: 3, y: 1, size: 2, color: '#00BCD4' },
                    { id: "n2", label: "node 3", x: 1, y: 3, size: 1, color: '#00BCD4' },
                    { id: "n3", label: "node 4", x: 6, y: 0, size: 3, color: '#00BCD4' },
                    { id: "n4", label: "node 5", x: 5, y: 1, size: 2, color: '#00BCD4' },
                    { id: "n5", label: "node 6", x: 4, y: 3, size: 1, color: '#00BCD4' }
                  ],
                  edges: [
                    { id: "e0", source: "n0", target: "n1",  color: '#545454', type:'line'},
                    { id: "e1", source: "n1", target: "n2", color: '#545454', type:'line'},
                    { id: "e2", source: "n1", target: "n3", color: '#545454', type:'line'},
                    { id: "e3", source: "n1", target: "n4", color: '#545454', type:'line'},
                    { id: "e4", source: "n2", target: "n0", color: '#545454', type:'line'},
                    { id: "e5", source: "n2", target: "n3", color: '#545454', type:'line'},
                    { id: "e6", source: "n3", target: "n2",  color: '#545454', type:'line'},
                    { id: "e7", source: "n4", target: "n5", color: '#545454', type:'line'},
                    { id: "e8", source: "n4", target: "n3", color: '#545454', type:'line'},
                    { id: "e9", source: "n5", target: "n0", color: '#545454', type:'line'}
                  ]
                }

                s.graph.read(graph);
                s.refresh();
            });
        }
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onload()">
    <div id='sigma-container'></div>
    
  
  </body>
</html>
```

I encountered error below, when I browse to index.html.
[image]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please review your build/deploy process, what you do here is really a mess : manual deploy inside tomcat, npm installation in tomcat, adding content into node_modules, ...

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the source of the Sigma and the minified version is compatible with AMD modules, here is your example, slightly modified, but working:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js" integrity="sha512-c3Nl8+7g4LMSTdrm621y7kf9v3SDPnhxLNhcjFJbKECVnmZHTdo+IRO05sNLTH/D3vA6u1X32ehoLC7WFVdheg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <style>
        html { height:100%; color: #fff!important;}
        body {height: 100%; margin:0; color: #fff!important;}
        #sigma-container { width:100%; height:100%;  color: #fff!important;}
        #sigma-mouse{
            background: transparent;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onload(){
            require([
                "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/2.1.2/sigma.min.js"
            ], function(sigma){
                console.log(sigma);
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onload()">
<div id='sigma-container'></div>


</body>
</html>
```